# How to move content below the UISearchBar when entering a DetailView

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar set up with its controller on a TableViewController and everything works great when a user looks for something in the searchbar. When the user clicks on a TableView Cell while doing a search, it performs a "show" segue to a Detail View, but the searchBar remains hovering over the top part of the DetailView's content.

I have been looking for information all over the place on how to move the content under the active searchBar, and how to move the content to its original place when the user clicks cancel on the searchBar, but I have not found any.

I tried sending the searchBar's height on "prepareforsegue" and using this height to do an offset on the scrollview that holds the content on the DetailView, which works. But when the user cancels the search, the searchBar disappears leaving a white space between the scrollView holding the content and the superview. I tried using the **searchBarCancelButtonClicked** function of the UISearchBarDelegate (and set the delegate on the class as well), but it does not work on iOS9.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     //Reset the scrollView insets here to the its original position.
}
```

**1. Has any of you made the "searchBarCancelButtonClicked" work on iOS9? If so, how?**

**2. Is there an out-of-the box code to move the view's content if the searchBar is active, and move it to its original position if the search is canceled?**

Comment: Do you mean that if you are searching and you click on a row under the active search it bugs out? And otherwise it´s working?

Comment: Nope! It performs the segue succesfully while the searchBar is active. Once the DetalView appears, the upper section does not show because the searchBar is displaying over the content.

This is the DetailView with the searchBar active, clipping/hidding the upper portion of the content:
http://imageshack.com/a/img903/470/avWB31.png

This is the complete DetailView's content (how it's supposed to look like under the searchBar):
http://imageshack.com/a/img907/4130/Vhuu2R.png

Comment: You have two views, have you added the searchBar to both views? Otherwise have you tried in your first viewControllers viewWillAppear adding searchBar.hidden = false and in the detailViewControllers viewWIllAppear adding searchBar.hidden = true

Comment: Do I need to add a search bar to both views?. I only have it defined on the 1st view controller. When I click on a tableView cell on the 1st view controller, it takes me to the 2nd view controller and the search bar is still active (which is what I want so that if the user by seeing the Detail realizes it was not the item he was looking for, he can go back through navigation and continue scrolling on the filteredResults based on the text written on the searchBar)